# C# Collection properties should be read only

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, collections

I've run the code analysis in Visual Studio and got following warning:

> CA2227: Collection properties should be read only.

I know what it means and why I shouldn't have a public set.
But I'm not sure how to deal with it.

In my `ViewModel` I have this property:

```
private ObservableCollection<Foo> _foos = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();

public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos
{
    get { return _foos; }
    set
    {
        _foos = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

This property is bound to the view.

The logic how to fill this collection is in the business layer. There's a function which returns a

```
ObservableCollection<Foo>
```

If Foos has no setter I can't do this.

```
Foos = BusinessLayer.GetFoos();
```

I can do this:

```
_foos = BusinessLayer.GetFoos();
OnPropertyChanged("Foos");
```

or this:

```
var foos = BusinessLayer.GetFoos();
foreach(var foo in foos) 
{
    Foos.Add(foo);
}
```

Which is the appropriate way? Are there better ways?

Comment: I agree that Collection properties should be read-only. Instantiate the collection once, from inside your class. Then deal with it's Items, not with the collection itself.

Comment: BTW, your business layer shouldn't return ObservableCollections. That's a ViewModel concept which has nothing to do with Business Logic.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
Foos.Clear();
Foos.AddRange(BusinessLayer.GetFoos());
```

However, this code loses any updates.

Comment: "this code loses any updates." Huh?  As long as Foos is an ObservableCollection, anybody bound to it will see collection update events and should react appropriately.  Using an INPC property to expose an ObservableCollection is a code smell.

Comment: I meant updates from the business layer to the view model - if anybody changes `BusinessLayer.GetFoos()`, you have to update the collection in the view model on your own.

Comment: ObservableCollection doesn't support AddRange

Comment: @Dani: Then add them one by one.  He's just saying "add the elements returned from the business layer to the collection."  You can do that, right?